# java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1 While switch between 2 surfaceview

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

Hi I'm trying to switch between 2 surfaceviews, so on the first surfaceview I want show the camera for record  and in the other one I want to show the recorded video.

I've got an exception :

> java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1

This is my logcat:

```
03-09 14:33:30.085: V/MediaPlayer(14492): constructor
03-09 14:33:30.085: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Client(136) constructor
03-09 14:33:30.085: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Create new client(136) from pid 23263, uid 10003, 
03-09 14:33:30.085: I/MediaPlayerFactory(14492): Can`t play mp3 and ogg file on NuPlayer , create Awesomeplayer.
03-09 14:33:30.085: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): player type = 3
03-09 14:33:30.090: V/MediaPlayerService(14492):  setDataSource
03-09 14:33:30.090: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [136] setParameter(1604)
03-09 14:33:30.090: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [136] getParameter(1700)
03-09 14:33:30.090: V/MediaPlayer(14492): MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
03-09 14:33:30.090: V/MediaPlayer(14492): prepare
03-09 14:33:30.090: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [136] setAudioStreamType(7)
03-09 14:33:30.090: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [136] prepareAsync
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [136] notify (0x42bf7090, 200, 973, 0)
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayer(14492): message received msg=200, ext1=973, ext2=0
03-09 14:33:30.095: W/MediaPlayer(14492): info/warning (973, 0)
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [136] notify (0x42bf7090, 5, 0, 0)
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayer(14492): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayer(14492): New video size 0 x 0
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [136] notify (0x42bf7090, 1, 0, 0)
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayer(14492): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayer(14492): prepared
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayer(14492): signal application thread
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayer(14492): prepare complete - status=0
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayer(14492): constructor
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Client(137) constructor
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Create new client(137) from pid 23263, uid 10003, 
03-09 14:33:30.095: I/MediaPlayerFactory(14492): Can`t play mp3 and ogg file on NuPlayer , create Awesomeplayer.
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): player type = 3
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayerService(14492):  setDataSource
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] setParameter(1604)
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] getParameter(1700)
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayer(14492): MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayer(14492): prepare
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] setAudioStreamType(7)
03-09 14:33:30.095: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] prepareAsync
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] notify (0x42be0008, 200, 973, 0)
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayer(14492): message received msg=200, ext1=973, ext2=0
03-09 14:33:30.100: W/MediaPlayer(14492): info/warning (973, 0)
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] notify (0x42be0008, 5, 0, 0)
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayer(14492): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayer(14492): New video size 0 x 0
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] notify (0x42be0008, 1, 0, 0)
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayer(14492): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayer(14492): prepared
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayer(14492): signal application thread
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayer(14492): prepare complete - status=0
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayer(14492): constructor
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Client(138) constructor
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Create new client(138) from pid 23263, uid 10003, 
03-09 14:33:30.100: I/MediaPlayerFactory(14492): Can`t play mp3 and ogg file on NuPlayer , create Awesomeplayer.
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): player type = 3
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayerService(14492):  setDataSource
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] setParameter(1604)
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] getParameter(1700)
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayer(14492): MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayer(14492): prepare
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] setAudioStreamType(7)
03-09 14:33:30.100: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] prepareAsync
03-09 14:33:30.105: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] notify (0x427b8990, 200, 973, 0)
03-09 14:33:30.105: V/MediaPlayer(14492): message received msg=200, ext1=973, ext2=0
03-09 14:33:30.105: W/MediaPlayer(14492): info/warning (973, 0)
03-09 14:33:30.105: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] notify (0x427b8990, 5, 0, 0)
03-09 14:33:30.105: V/MediaPlayer(14492): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-09 14:33:30.105: V/MediaPlayer(14492): New video size 0 x 0
03-09 14:33:30.105: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] notify (0x427b8990, 1, 0, 0)
03-09 14:33:30.105: V/MediaPlayer(14492): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-09 14:33:30.105: V/MediaPlayer(14492): prepared
03-09 14:33:30.105: V/MediaPlayer(14492): signal application thread
03-09 14:33:30.105: V/MediaPlayer(14492): prepare complete - status=0
03-09 14:33:30.710: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Create new media recorder client from pid 23263
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayer(14492): MediaPlayer::setVolume(0.500000, 0.500000)
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] setVolume(0.500000, 0.500000)
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayer(14492): seekTo 0
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): getDuration
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] getDuration = 387
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] seekTo(0)
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] notify (0x42be0008, 4, 0, 0)
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayer(14492): message received msg=4, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayer(14492): Received seek complete
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayer(14492): All seeks complete - return to regularly scheduled program
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayer(14492): start
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] setLooping(0)
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] setVolume(0.500000, 0.500000)
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] setAuxEffectSendLevel(0.000000)
03-09 14:33:36.140: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] start
03-09 14:33:36.695: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [137] notify (0x42be0008, 2, 0, 0)
03-09 14:33:36.695: V/MediaPlayer(14492): message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-09 14:33:36.695: V/MediaPlayer(14492): playback complete
03-09 14:33:41.600: V/MediaPlayer(14492): MediaPlayer::setVolume(0.500000, 0.500000)
03-09 14:33:41.600: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] setVolume(0.500000, 0.500000)
03-09 14:33:41.600: V/MediaPlayer(14492): seekTo 0
03-09 14:33:41.600: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): getDuration
03-09 14:33:41.600: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] getDuration = 93
03-09 14:33:41.600: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] seekTo(0)
03-09 14:33:41.600: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] notify (0x427b8990, 4, 0, 0)
03-09 14:33:41.600: V/MediaPlayer(14492): message received msg=4, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-09 14:33:41.600: V/MediaPlayer(14492): Received seek complete
03-09 14:33:41.600: V/MediaPlayer(14492): All seeks complete - return to regularly scheduled program
03-09 14:33:41.600: V/MediaPlayer(14492): start
03-09 14:33:41.605: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] setLooping(0)
03-09 14:33:41.605: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] setVolume(0.500000, 0.500000)
03-09 14:33:41.605: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] setAuxEffectSendLevel(0.000000)
03-09 14:33:41.605: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] start
03-09 14:33:41.930: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [138] notify (0x427b8990, 2, 0, 0)
03-09 14:33:41.930: V/MediaPlayer(14492): message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-09 14:33:41.930: V/MediaPlayer(14492): playback complete
03-09 14:33:45.720: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Delete media recorder client
03-09 14:33:45.910: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(23263): native_setup
03-09 14:33:45.910: V/MediaPlayer(23263): constructor
03-09 14:33:45.910: V/MediaPlayer(14492): disconnect
03-09 14:33:45.915: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): disconnect(136) from pid 23263
03-09 14:33:45.915: V/MediaPlayer(23263): setListener
03-09 14:33:45.915: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Client(136) destructor pid = 23263
03-09 14:33:45.915: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): disconnect(136) from pid 23263
03-09 14:33:45.920: V/MediaPlayer(14492): destructor
03-09 14:33:45.920: V/MediaPlayer(14492): disconnect
03-09 14:33:45.920: V/MediaPlayer(14492): disconnect
03-09 14:33:45.920: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): disconnect(137) from pid 23263
03-09 14:33:45.920: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Client(137) destructor pid = 23263
03-09 14:33:45.920: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): disconnect(137) from pid 23263
03-09 14:33:45.920: V/MediaPlayer(14492): destructor
03-09 14:33:45.920: V/MediaPlayer(14492): disconnect
03-09 14:33:45.920: V/MediaPlayer(14492): disconnect
03-09 14:33:45.920: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): disconnect(138) from pid 23263
03-09 14:33:45.925: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Client(138) destructor pid = 23263
03-09 14:33:45.925: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): disconnect(138) from pid 23263
03-09 14:33:45.925: V/MediaPlayer(14492): destructor
03-09 14:33:45.925: V/MediaPlayer(14492): disconnect
03-09 14:33:45.970: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(23263): setDataSourceFD: fd 65
03-09 14:33:45.970: V/MediaPlayer(23263): setDataSource(65, 0, 576460752303423487)
03-09 14:33:45.970: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Client(139) constructor
03-09 14:33:45.970: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Create new client(139) from pid 23263, uid 10003, 
03-09 14:33:45.970: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): setDataSource fd=31, offset=0, length=576460752303423487
03-09 14:33:45.970: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): st_dev  = 18
03-09 14:33:45.970: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): st_mode = 33204
03-09 14:33:45.970: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): st_uid  = 0
03-09 14:33:45.970: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): st_gid  = 1015
03-09 14:33:45.970: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): st_size = 9557981
03-09 14:33:45.970: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): calculated length = 9557981
03-09 14:33:45.970: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): player type = 3
03-09 14:33:45.990: V/MediaPlayerService(14492):  setDataSource
03-09 14:33:45.990: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [139] setParameter(1604)
03-09 14:33:45.990: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [139] getParameter(1700)
03-09 14:33:45.990: V/MediaPlayer(23263): setVideoSurfaceTexture
03-09 14:33:45.990: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [139] setVideoSurfaceTexture(0x42e6cfb8)
03-09 14:33:54.025: V/MediaPlayer(23263): setVideoSurfaceTexture
03-09 14:33:54.025: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [139] setVideoSurfaceTexture(0x4309a338)
03-09 14:33:54.025: V/MediaPlayer(23263): prepare
03-09 14:33:54.025: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [139] setAudioStreamType(3)
03-09 14:33:54.025: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [139] prepareAsync
03-09 14:33:54.035: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [139] notify (0x42bf7090, 100, 1, -2147483648)
03-09 14:33:54.040: V/MediaPlayer(23263): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
03-09 14:33:54.040: E/MediaPlayer(23263): error (1, -2147483648)
03-09 14:33:54.040: V/MediaPlayer(23263): signal application thread
03-09 14:33:54.040: V/MediaPlayer(23263): prepare complete - status=1
03-09 14:34:10.840: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(23263): setAudioStreamType: 3
03-09 14:34:10.840: V/MediaPlayer(23263): MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
03-09 14:34:10.840: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(23263): setVolume: left 0.000000  right 0.000000
03-09 14:34:10.840: V/MediaPlayer(23263): MediaPlayer::setVolume(0.000000, 0.000000)
03-09 14:34:10.840: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): [139] setVolume(0.000000, 0.000000)
03-09 14:34:10.845: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(23263): start
03-09 14:34:10.845: V/MediaPlayer(23263): start
03-09 14:34:10.845: E/MediaPlayer(23263): start called in state 0
03-09 14:34:10.845: V/MediaPlayer(23263): message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
03-09 14:34:10.845: E/MediaPlayer(23263): error (-38, 0)
03-09 14:34:10.845: V/MediaPlayer(23263): callback application
03-09 14:34:10.850: V/MediaPlayer(23263): back from callback
03-09 14:34:12.225: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Client(139) destructor pid = 23263
03-09 14:34:12.225: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): disconnect(139) from pid 23263
03-09 14:34:29.970: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Create new media retriever from pid 22479
03-09 14:34:30.900: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Create new media retriever from pid 22479
03-09 14:34:31.400: V/MediaPlayerService(14492): Create new media retriever from pid 22479
```

I added only the MediaPlayer Tag.
If more information is needed please ask it.

Thanks!

Comment: So you're trying to use `MediaPlayer` to play the video as it's being recorded?  Why do you have two `SurfaceViews` -- aren't they essentially the same thing (one showing what you're recording, one playing back the recorded file)?  It might be useful to explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I believe that I don't need 2 surface views.  You are right I just need to preview the recorded video. It's this complecated to perform this on one surface view?

Comment: Something like "Show + capture camera" or "Constant capture" in https://github.com/google/grafika ?

Comment: If I don't want to use GLSurfaceView. Is there a easier way to do it with a regular SurfaceView? or with a VideoView?

Comment: `GLSurfaceView` and `VideoView` are both subclasses of `SurfaceView`.  They do a bunch of work for you, but they're fundamentally the same.  The "Constant capture" activity uses a plain `SurfaceView`.  Showing the camera is trivial (see "Live camera (TextureView)"), recording the camera preview is reasonably straightforward (see http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#CameraToMpegTest), doing both at the same time is slightly more complex.